Should all AI based questions be closed immediately for lack of clarity unless they follow specific guardrails?
LLMs and chatbots like ChatGPT are all the rage these days. And AI in general is a philosophic topic as it relates to Mind, physicalism and so on.
Yet most people do not know or understand the underlying technology to ask questions with sufficient quality or answer them.
As an example, all of those lack clarity (without even reading the rest of such questions):

Does AI...
Do AI agents...
Do computers...?
Do software programs...?
Do LLMs...?
Does ChatGpt...?

These are all underspecified. There is no such single thing as AI that could be subject to analysis, but infinitely many completely different technologies. There is no such thing as "the AI Agent", AI related technologies is present in all kinds of devices, not just ChatGPT but also coffee machines, cars, doorbells, vacuum cleaners. All of those have very different types.
As an analogy, "AI" summarizes as many different technologies under it's label as "life" does. Asking "Does AI have beliefs" is Aki. To asking "there is something living in the room with me, does it have beliefs?" Without specifying if that something is a human, a dog, a fly, a bacteria, a mould, a virus ...
Even when talking about "ChatGPT" the product, the questions lack clarity as apps under that label are very different from version to version (And with A/B testing even different between user sessions, my ChatGPT might do things yours can't). A question would have to be precise about the exact version used, else any answer would become invalid the next year.
This makes the topic likely to start fights every time an asker finds the topic SO FASCINATING that they throw a losely put together question at the site. It also means in every such question, for every answer, the answerer first has to educate the asker about all those issues with the terminology. I would like to prevent the recurring drama of lengthy discussions and close votes and reopening petitions, and have a standard on what clarity on the technology is required to keep a question valid under "lacking clarity" requirements.
I would suggest that any question has to specify what technology it asks about in sufficient detail. (in text or via an acceptable link. Like Wikipedia. Not any link like https://chatgpt.com/ which changes constantly with updates). This also includes being explicit about non-specificity such as saying "any LLM based chatbot without access to other data sources" or similar, instead of just saying "ChatGPT" under some assumption of how that product is built.
The specification must be so that a computer scientist could decide whether any implementation is a realization of the specification or not (which in other words means, if you don't understand computer science, you cannot ask philosophy questions about chatbots. You would first need to learn about the technology, e.g. by reading books or asking questions on other sites).
In principle this is no different from other topics

for questions about philosophy and cosmology, you need to understand cosmology (and relativity)
for questions about philosophy and quantum theory, you need to understand quantum theory
for questions about evolution, you need to understand evolution
for questions about gender and sexuality, you need to understand gender and sexuality sciences
... and so on

For some topic this works well naturally, but for others askers feel entitled to ask questions with nothing but a very superficial understanding, and ChatGPT is such a topic because anyone can install a client app on their smartphone with 2 clicks and feel like an expert after asking 3 questions.

The whole point of asking questions is to learn things, so ignorance of how certain things operate is irrelevant to a question filled stack exchange. Secondly, the questions on this stack exchange are not directly computer science related, but rather about the philosophies pertaining to AI, and so a questioner having a lack of detailed knowledge about how AI works from a technological standpoint is again, irrelevant

I think there's a middleground here between MisterMiyagi's "black box" mysticism and tkruse's specificity requirement.  Much of what I consider relates to the technology of transformer-architecture large language models, and the probability weighting of semantic tokens is really interesting in terms of how we like to discuss concepts of modality and number in our metaphysical model building. ...

...  But even something as basic as IP telephony has implications philosophically - why this set of possible choices of message? People need an in-route to these technologies, and we tend to start at the level of intuition before we go to details.  (upvoted your question btw - important conversation to have!)

If a technology were a black box, how would any philosopher have been able to discuss anything about the internals? How could any answer on this site be validated as true if those details are unknown?

Then a question should be able to be specific about which publicly known mechanisms it is talking about.

I think the real issue is about the disconnect between what most people think about AI (e.g. Terminator's Skynet, Tony Stark's JARVIS) vs what these (Gen)AI actually do (statistical computation). I can see causative's argument that it might be better to move further from specific and instead focus on general abstraction. Whether that will produce meaningful Q&A in practice, is a different question...

I want to note that I have the same problems here but about most every question, e.g. "know" or "thing" or "cause" etc are underspecified. I'm not saying those all need to be closed, but I don't think this is unique to AI buzzwords.

No.
So you're claiming that AI questions should name a specific technology implementing it.
AI in philosophy is frequently abstracted from any specific implementation. This is because philosophers often want to ask questions about some ultimate endpoint of AI - artificial consciousness, or AGI. We do not know what specific technology this endpoint would involve.
What we can say, useful for philosophical purposes, is that it would be an algorithm running on a computer. This is useful, philosophically, because it implies:

The algorithm can be described by some mathematical formulas describing what happens next.
Every byte of the state of the algorithm can be inspected by software tools.
This state can be paused, or copied from place to place and run as multiple instances.
Because the algorithm is mathematical, we would expect any proposition about the algorithm to, in principle, also be amenable to mathematical analysis.

In principle, perhaps these things are true of the human brain, but that is much more contentious and less clear. In practice the state of the human brain is far more difficult to inspect and manipulate.
So to summarize, by speaking about AI instead of the human brain, we set a number of expectations and assumptions about how the analysis might go, different from the usual expectations and assumptions when we speak about human brains and human minds. This provides specificity and value, without the need or desire to name a specific AI technology.

Even when talking about "ChatGPT" the product, the questions lack clarity as apps under that label are very different from version to version (And with A/B testing even different between user sessions, my ChatGPT might do things yours can't). A question would have to be precise about the exact version used, else any answer would become invalid the next year.

It's difficult to see the philosophical value of naming an AI technology to the level of specificity of "what exact version of ChatGPT." There are broad categories that it may be useful to speak about in a philosophical context: LLMs, reinforcement learners, rule-based expert systems, Bayesian networks, causal graphs, etc. But naming a specific version number of a specific product? Hard to see how that helps.

More importantly, obviously, "how does ChatGPT v4.0.23.5a relate its corpus and reinforcement learning to questions of intention" is clearly about ChatGPT.  That's not necessarily the question someone coming here intends to ask.

A question can also be clear about the non-specificy. That is a question can be explicit about what kinds/versions of technologies it includes and not, rather than leaving that open to interpretation in each answer.

Also version ranges such a GPT 3.x could be used

"Closed immediately"? I would say "no". It's not impossible to write a useful question that uses the term "AI", one that is specific enough to be answered.
That said, AI is, as you note, the new hotness, and will generate lots of low-quality questions. I think it's reasonable upon seeing the term "AI" in a question to be looking to see that it's based in some specific, possible reality. I wouldn't be surprised to see that AI questions get closed more often, but some areas just attract and generate more low-quality discourse.

I might have phrased the suggestion in a slightly exaggerated way, as an opening.

I appreciate a good use of rhetoric. Heck, Socrates invented a new mode of discussion that they named after him. (I'm now expecting to be corrected on the actual origins of the Socratic dialog, which is one of the pleasures of hanging out with actual philosophers.)
